# Docker and ECR credentials to ./docker/config

Tags: docker, amazon-ecr

I am configuring both the docker and ecr-login on one of our mesos nodes. But when I have tried the ecr credentials docker is failing to pull images.

Can anyone had it working for Docker version 1.11.2, build b9f10c9

```
    {
      "auths": {
        "docker.xxxxx.com": {
          "auth": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        },
       "xxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com": {}
      },
      "credsStore": "ecr-login"
    }

i also tried this 

{
  "auths": {
    "docker.xxxxxxxx.com": {
      "auth": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    }
  },
  "credsStore": "ecr-login",
  "auths": {
   "xxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com": {}
  }
}
```

Error:

Pulling repository docker.xxxxx.com/docker
Error: image docker not found

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're using v1.11.2? It released in 2016-05-31.

Answer (score 1):

For Docker 1.11, you cannot use both "auths" and "credsStore" at the same time.  If you want to use the [credential helper](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-ecr-credential-helper), you'd configure it as follows:

```
{"credsStore":"ecr-login"}
```

If you still want to authenticate against `docker.xxxxx.com`, you'd need to either not use the credential helper or use a separate config file (you can override the location by setting the `DOCKER_CONFIG` environment variable).

Newer versions of Docker support using both "auths" and "credsStore" at the same time.  Newer versions of Docker also address a variety of security issues that are not fixed in Docker 1.11.